# spring kafka listener is looking ContainerProperties at wrong place

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to use kafka listener in my spring boot application, but the server start is failing with the below error: The root cause is that it is looking for ContainerProperties in `org.springframework.kafka.listener.config` subpackage where it is available in `org.springframework.kafka.listener`

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties()Lorg/springframework/kafka/listener/config/ContainerProperties; but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/kumarman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/kafka/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/kumarman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer
```

my dependency graph is:

```
lon2002619:wmt-service kumarman$ mvn dependency:tree | grep kafka
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:test:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:jar:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:jar:test:2.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-kafka11:jar:2.7.3:compile
```

And the kafka configuration code is:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getGroupId());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getAutoOffsetReset());

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, byte[]> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, byte[]> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, byte[]> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Stacktrace after enabling trace log:

```
2018-11-29 10:51:05.292 TRACE [kumarman-wmt-service,,,] 46241 --- [           main] o.s.c.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader   : Loaded [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalysisReporter] names: [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter]
2018-11-29 10:51:05.301 DEBUG [kumarman-wmt-service,,,] 46241 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties()Lorg/springframework/kafka/listener/config/ContainerProperties;
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.messaging.SleuthKafkaAspect.wrapListenerContainerCreation(TraceMessagingAutoConfiguration.java:191) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d4611e6.createListenerContainer(<generated>) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.createListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:183) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:155) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:129) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.registerAllEndpoints(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:164) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar.java:158) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:259) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.betstars.wmt.app.WmtServiceApplication.main(WmtServiceApplication.java:14) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [wmt-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [wmt-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [wmt-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [wmt-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
```

Pom Extract:

```
<spring.boot.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
<!-- Zipkin - tracing -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a mix up of versions in your project. Please, consider to fully reply on the Spring Boot dependencies.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? spring-kafka 2.2 will only work with Spring Boot 2.1

Comment: @GaryRussell we are using spring boot 2.1, and haven't overwritten version of spring-kafka. spring-kafka 2.2 is coming inbuilt with spring boot 2.1

Comment: @ArtemBilan as in previous comment, we re not giving any version to kafka anywhere. And the dependency tree also highlight only one version of kafka.

Comment: OK. Can you share a simple project on GitHub to let us to reproduce and play with what you have so far?

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan I don't have the code access at home. I will create a git project tomorrow.

Comment: Perhaps you are referencing it from your code?

Comment: @GaryRussell nailed it on the head, needing to upgrade from 2.0.5 to latest 2.1.3 solved it! I dont understand why would they introduce such breaking backward compatibility issues in minor versions! (We had Spring-Kafka on 2.1.10 initially so upgrade to 2.2.4 should not have broken it so badly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are referencing it on your code?

It was moved from listener.config to listener in 2.2.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/b048aaa8f00045e4cc65d5d137b1aa372beca3a2#diff-7121e19c8f33f6bddfd42b749f0bddb0

See the [what's new](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/whats-new-part.html#_class_package_changes).

**EDIT**

I was able to reproduce your issue with the following contrived example:

Compile this class against spring-kafka 2.0...

```
public class Foo {

    public void referenceOldClass(KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container) {
        container.getContainerProperties();
    }

}
```

Then reference that class from a Boot 2.1 application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So53503830Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53503830Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Autowired
    private ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            ContainerProperties props = new ContainerProperties("topic");
            KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(this.cf,  props);
            foo.referenceOldClass(container);
        };
    }

}
```

With DEBUG logging, we get the stack trace...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties()Lorg/springframework/kafka/listener/config/ContainerProperties;
    at com.example.Foo.referenceOldClass(Foo.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.So53503830Application.lambda$0(So53503830Application.java:32) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:794) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.So53503830Application.main(So53503830Application.java:16) [classes/:na]

2018-11-28 15:02:56.962 ERROR 95564 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties()Lorg/springframework/kafka/listener/config/ContainerProperties; but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/grussell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/grussell/.m2/repository/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer
```

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell, I will inspect the code tomorrow!

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, there is no reference of ContainerProperties in my code, and as dependency tree shows there is single kafka library. This application is having rabbit mq library too. Do you think it might get confused with the rabbitmq library? I created a cut-down version of the application and it is working as expected.

Comment: Something in your app was compiled against an older version. Which rabbitmq library? `spring-rabbit` uses `com.rabbitmq:amqp-client`. I wonder if Boot will give you a full stack trace if you enable DEBUG logging?

Comment: we had used default spring-rabbit. We tried debug mode, and  AbstractMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties() was throwing the stacktrace complaining for the package mismatch. I will try to generate the stacktrace and will add in the question.

Comment: I could reproduce your situation with a contrived example; the stack trace should tell you what's using the old class. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: The stacktrace was not thrown from the custom class, but it is throwing when it is trying to create Bean kafkaListenerContainerFactory, and calling new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

Comment: That's not what the error says; please add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: I tried to generate it but it failed due to out of office network. I will generate the trace tomorrow morning, I will add it in the question.

Comment: Note that I won't get a notification if you post something in the chat so you should comment here.

Comment: Thanks @Gary, it suggested moving to chat, and I clicked it.

Comment: Yes, I know  but, unfortunately, notes in chat don't generate a notification so I won't know when you post something there and I don't have time to keep checking. We prefer GItter for extended discussions.

Comment: nice idea Gary. I didn't know we are not getting a notification there.

Comment: I have added the stacktrace now and it looks like it is coming from sleuth and we may need a spring-cloud upgrade to Greenwich, but can't see its release is not working.

Comment: Yes, you need Greenwich for Boot 2.1. A new initializr project pulls in milestone 3 `<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M3</spring-cloud.version>`. I believe it will be released next month some time.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell, it worked after removing spring cloud zipkin library.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. My solution was

```
spring.sleuth.messaging.kafka.enabled = false.
```

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.0.1.RELEASE/multi/multi__integrations.html#_spring_kafka

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#spring-kafka

> 15.10.3. Spring Kafka
>   We instrument the Spring Kafka’s ProducerFactory and ConsumerFactory so that tracing headers get injected into the created Spring Kafka’s Producer and Consumer.

To block this feature, set spring.sleuth.messaging.kafka.enabled to false.